# Cannot find IBM MobileFirst 8.0.0 Studio Plugin for Eclipse Mars

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have Eclipse Mars (4.5.3) and I am not able to find MFP 8.0 Studio plugin in the Eclipse marketplace. I am able to install the "Thym" plugin but when I search for MFP 8 plugin, it gives me nothing.

Comment: I see the issue is only with Mars. Juno shows the option. Will update

Answer (score 1):

While we are investigating this, at present, you can install the plugin directly in Eclipse mars by following the below step

```
help -> install new software -> add
```

Add this URL to the location

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/

Comment: Hi,

After installing MFP 8 Pulgin and Thym 2.0 in eclipse, I don't get the option to create a project (It is not giving an option to create a project)

Comment: Will the MFP 8 plugin work with Eclipse Oxygen? I don't see it available in the marketplace with Oxygen but I do see the Thym plugin. Also, if we are not using the MFP Server for anything, do we need the MFP plugin?